# Is it possible to convert strings to shapes in python?

Tags: python, pip

So I want to convert strings to shapes after being given a certain string by the user.
e.g "I love squares" = square shape.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also explain how your question is related to `pip` which is one of tags you applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about just looking for the word to convert to in the string? something like this:

```
userstring = "I love squares"
if not userstring.find('squares') == -1:
    create_square()
if not userstring.find('circle') == -1:
    create_circle()
#etc etc
```

Comment: create square not defined error?

Comment: Python doesn't have "shapes", so yes, that's an error. If you want a better answer you'll need to ask a better question. I've explained how you could do it, and assumed you knew that "create_square()" is a function that creates a shape you defined.